# React Router with path like /list/:page does not work on reload

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, router, webpack-dev-server

I have multiple routes setup like this:

```
<Route path="/" exact={true} component={test0} />
<Route path="/test1" exact={true} component={test1} />
<Route path="/test2" exact={true} component={test2} />
<Route path="/test3/options" exact={true} component={test3} />
<Route path="/test4/data/:id" exact={true} component={test4} />
<Route path="/list/:page" exact={true} component={list} />
```

Normal Routing is working when we click on links.

But when i manually reload browser page it only work for paths: /, /test1 and /test2

Page reload does not work for path /test3/options, /test4/data/:id (eg: /test4/data/4) and /list/:page (eg: /list/3)

My dev-server config is:

```
devServer: {
  liveReload: true,
  stats: "errors-only",
  hot: true,
  historyApiFallback: true
}
```

React Router and React Router DOM version installed

```
"react-router": "^5.0.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
```

Any help is appreciated.

> UPDATE:

[image: Console Error]
This error appears on all the paths that are not working on Reload.
the actual path for bundle.min.js file should be 
`http://localhost:8080/bundle.min.js`
i think the problem is here

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  filename: "bundle.min.js"
},
```

Comment: Ah, "does not work", that means you must have done something wrong. What you've done wrong nobody knows because there isn't enough information here. Maybe you can provide a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-react-webpack-xeq1x) and/or explain what "does not work" means (expected behavior versus actual behavior and errors).

Comment: not working after reload might indicate a serverside configuration problem

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Found [this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback) on Webpack dev server page

and added few rules, changed my webpack dev server config

> From This:

```
devServer: {
  liveReload: true,
  stats: "errors-only",
  hot: true,
  historyApiFallback: true
}
```

> To This:

```
devServer: {
  liveReload: true,
  stats: "errors-only",
  hot: true,
  historyApiFallback: {
    rewrites: [
      { from: /\/(bundle.min.js$)/, to: 'http://localhost:8080/bundle.min.js' },
      { from: /http:\/\/localhost:8080\/*/, to: 'http://localhost:8080' }
    ]
  }
}
```